# Finding Minimum Dates for Clients in SQL Query compare columns and multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a query where like this

```
with CTE AS (
        select 
            CLIENT.client_number AS CLIENT_NUMBER, 
            CAST(CLient.create_date AS DATE)AS CLIENT_CREATE_DATE, 
            CAST(ACCOUNT.account_open AS DATE) AS ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE 
            from ACCOUNT
LEFT JOIN CLIENT ON CAST (CLIENT.client_number AS NUMERIC) = ACCOUNT.client_number
)
select 
CLIENT_NUMBER,
CLIENT_CREATE_DATE,
ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE,
'' NEW_CLIENT_DATE
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CLIENT_NUMBER
```

and the result i get is :

```
CLIENT_NUMBER   CLIENT_CREATE_DATE  ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE     NEW_CLIENT_DATE
5                   1/10/2014           8/21/2001                
7                   1/10/2014           3/24/2010   
7                   1/10/2014           10/31/2011  
13                  1/10/2014           4/5/2012    
16                  1/10/2014           10/16/2003  
16                  1/10/2014           6/14/2022   
16                  1/10/2014           8/24/2011   
17                  1/10/2014           11/12/2014  
17                  1/10/2014           12/10/2014  
18                  1/10/2014           10/23/2003
```

How can I determine the earliest date for each client and insert it into the "NEW_CLIENT_DATE" column? The goal is to compare the "CLIENT_CREATE_DATE" with all associated "ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE" values for each client. If "CLIENT_CREATE_DATE" is the smallest, then set "NEW_CLIENT_DATE" to it; otherwise, set it to the smallest "ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE" for that client. I've attempted to use a CTE and tried partitioning, but I'm unsure how to proceed. Can someone guide me or provide a solution?

Output should be something like:

```
CLIENT_NUMBER   CLIENT_CREATE_DATE  ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE     NEW_CLIENT_DATE
5                   1/10/2014           8/21/2001               8/21/2001
7                   1/10/2014           3/24/2010               3/24/2010
7                   1/10/2014           10/31/2011              3/24/2010
13                  1/10/2014           4/5/2012                4/5/2012
16                  1/10/2014           10/16/2003              10/16/2003
16                  1/10/2014           6/14/2022               10/16/2003
16                  1/10/2014           8/24/2011               10/16/2003
17                  1/10/2014           11/12/2014              1/10/2014
17                  1/10/2014           12/10/2014              1/10/2014
18                  1/10/2014           10/23/2003              10/23/2003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the window functions here along with `CASE` logic:

```sql
SELECT 
    CLIENT_NUMBER,
    CLIENT_CREATE_DATE,
    ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE,
    CASE WHEN CLIENT_CREATE_DATE < MIN(ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_NUMBER)
         THEN CLIENT_CREATE_DATE
         ELSE MIN(ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENT_NUMBER) END AS NEW_CLIENT_DATE
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CLIENT_NUMBER;
```

Comment: i cant believe its this simple.
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Min Account Create Date in your CTE for each Client Number using a window function, then compare it with the Client Create Date in your outer select:

```
with CTE AS (
    select 
        c.client_number AS CLIENT_NUMBER, 
        CAST(c.CREATE_DATE AS DATE)AS CLIENT_CREATE_DATE, 
        CAST(a.ACCOUNT_OPEN AS DATE) AS ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE,
        min(a.ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE) over(partition by c.CLIENT_NUMBER) MinAccount
    from ACCOUNT a
    LEFT JOIN CLIENT c on CAST(c.CLIENT_NUMBER AS NUMERIC) = a.CLIENT_NUMBER
)
select 
CLIENT_NUMBER,
CLIENT_CREATE_DATE,
ACCOUNT_CREATE_DATE,
Iif(CLIENT_CREATE_DATE < MinAccount, CLIENT_CREATE_DATE , MinAccount) NEW_CLIENT_DATE
FROM CTE
ORDER BY CLIENT_NUMBER;
```

Also note how using aliases makes for a more readable query, and presumably the *unsargable* join predicate is not a performance issue for you...